# Updating datetime differently in different forms in a same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework, datetimepicker

I have a page with multiple forms. and i use datetime picker in code. i have tweaked datetime picker to show the date & time picked up by the user. But the problem is, when there are multiple forms in a page(say 2 tickets in a page), on selecting date & time in 1st ticket the same is reflected in both the forms. Since the datetime picker code is common to both forms, am not able to code in such a way that, time picked by 1st form should be shown in 1st forms calendar & time picked by 2nd form should be shown in 2nd forms calendar. How can i achieve this? Please let me know if any more info is needed.

Datepicker code:

$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({

```
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "calendarNew.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDateTime: new Date('<?php echo $time_entered_by_user;?>'),
    stepMinute: 5,
    timeText: "Time(UTC)    ",
    closeText: "Done"
});
```

Comment: without seeing some code, no one can offer much help.

Comment: It sounds like the date time pickers are named the same, but we need to see the code to help...

Comment: Sounds like both date pickers have the same ID. Make sure they have separate ID's when you create them.

Comment: No datepicker is inside a foreach hence the value given to it changes for every loop but issue is that it overwrites everytime and hence only the last value is seen in it

Comment: Also can anyone help in letting me know how to give UTC time to mindatetime field in datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like you have a repeating class and repeating elements. First of all, when you select your element that is being repeated you will receive a node list. you have to iterate through this node list and add an event listener to each of these items using vanilla js. With jQuery, it would be a little easier.

```
<li class="item">One</li>
<li class="item">Two</li>
<li class="item">Three</li>
<li class="item">Four</li>
<li class="item">Five</li>
<li class="item">Six</li>

let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

items.forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener('click', () => i.style.background = '#89FC00')
})
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6skp131x/

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

items.forEach(i => {
 i.addEventListener('click', () => i.style.background = '#89FC00')
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  
}
.item:nth-child(even){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="item">One</li>
<li class="item">Two</li>
<li class="item">Three</li>
<li class="item">Four</li>
<li class="item">Five</li>
<li class="item">Six</li>
```